# getenv() says a defined environment variable is undefined only when running in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, environment-variables

UPDATE: Eclipse is the problem -- it's working from console. But I'd still like it to work in Eclipse.

My printenv output contains the line:

```
PROTCAD3DIR=/home/brent/Desktop/protCAD
```

But from the program I'm trying to run (in Eclipse), I get output:

```
Environment variable PROTCAD3DIR undefined.
Please set it properly and re-execute the program.
```

I searched for this message in the source and found 1 result:

```
string PCGeneralIO::getEnvironmentVariable(const string& _evname)
{
    const char* convEVName = _evname.c_str();
    char* pEVString = getenv(convEVName);
    if (pEVString == 0)
    {   cout << "Environment variable " << _evname << " undefined." << endl;
        cout << "Please set it properly and re-execute the program." <<     endl;             
        exit(1);
    }               
    string EVstring = charToString(pEVString);    
    return EVstring;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is calling the above function:

```
string evname = "PROTCAD3DIR";
string path = PCGeneralIO::getEnvironmentVariable(evname);
```

So what could be causing getenv() to find it as undefined?

Comment: do you run your program in the same shell?

Comment: Is it possible that it runs under a different user context?

Comment: How do you invoke `getEnvironmentVariable()`? Any extraneous dollar signs?

Comment: I needed the variable to be permanent (across shells and restarts), so I added the definition and export within a file (.configuration or something of the like). printenv across different shells still shows the variable. I'm running the program from Eclipse.

Comment: @KerrekSB See my question edit at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Environment" Tab in the Eclipse "Run Configuration" for your program. The list should be empty and "Append environment to native environment" should be checked.

**Edit** if that does not help, then most probably Eclipse has not been started with the missing variable. Check this by creating a new "External Tool Configuration" using `/usr/bin/printenv` as the program. Start this external tool and examine the output. If the missing variable is not mentioned, then you have to specify *exactly* the

> I added the definition and export within a file (.configuration or something of the like).

part from your comment :-)

Comment: I just saw that it works in a shell, so Eclipse is indeed the problem. But what you described is how mine is actually. I was just now looking at it wondering if I have to add it manually. But I don't feel like I should have to, so any more suggestions?

Comment: @bbarre Maybe you just try to run you program from console? Just to make sure eclipse doesn't mess with env. vars?

Comment: @RomanB. It does indeed work from console. But I'd still like Eclipse to automatically pick up my envs.

Comment: Just to confirm, the missing variable is missing from the external tool output :/